# Getting CefSharp to correctly handle PDF files in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, mvvm, cefsharp

This problem does not impact WinForms.

I have downloaded the bare minimum example from the github site:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

As far as I am reasonably aware everything is up-to-date - I have used NuGet to make sure the latest CefSharp.Common, CefSharp.Wpf etc have been installed - currently version 53.

When I use it to browse web pages it's fine.  The problem is when I attempt to view a PDF-based page eg:

http://www.cbu.edu.zm/downloads/pdf-sample.pdf

So in the MainWindow.xaml I bind the 'Address' property to this value instead of "www.google.com":

```
<Window x:Class="CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
    Title="{Binding Path=Title, ElementName=Browser, Converter={StaticResource TitleConverter}}"
    WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0"
                            x:Name="Browser"
                            Address="http://www.cbu.edu.zm/downloads/pdf-sample.pdf" />
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="1">
        <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                     IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsLoading, ElementName=Browser}"
                     Width="100"
                     Height="16"
                     Margin="3" />
        <Separator />
        <!-- TODO: Could show hover link URL here -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address, ElementName=Browser}"/>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

When I run the example, in order to navigate to this PDF, the screen remains blank and the progress control does not update:

[image]

... unless I do something like un-maximise the browser window, or move it etc, then I can view it:

[image]

After this there is another strange problem whereby the scrollbars and +/- buttons appear to be unresponsive.  I notice that if I do press the '+' button for example and then another action such as maximize/restore - then the intended '+' action appears to have been carried out.  Ditto the scrollbar and other actions.

It does not exhibit this behaviour for the WinForms minimal example, if this helps, only the Wpf.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to replace this `<RowDefinition />` to this `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />`

Answer (score 1):

This has been raised as a duplicate of issue #1799 over at the GitHub site:

[WPF/OffScreen PDF Viewer not working #1799](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1799)

Until Version 55 is released, the solution as stated on the site is:

"Suggested workaround is to call Invalidate() on a timer as proposed on ceforum

You can roll back to 51 and use disable-surfaces or wait for version 55 to be released."

I found that rolling back to a previous version worked for me.

**UPDATE 21 Jan 2019**

This is no longer an issue with the more recent versions of CefSharp.